# Spring MVC - In which layer should entity association take place?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, associations

My question is somewhat similar to [In which layer should I join 2 entities together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512706/in-which-layer-should-i-join-2-entities-together) but I could not find a suitable answer.

Using JPA with Hibernate if relevant.

I have a model class `User` which has a one-to-many relationship with the class `Product`. A `Product` can not exist without a user.

After the form submission part of my app, I receive an instance of `Product` and a `User`'s ID; the product has not been linked to a `User` instance. To perform the association I need to:

1. Perform a lookup for the `User`
2. Call `User.addProduct()`
3. Persist changes to both models

My question is from a design perspective, where should these steps take place? From what I see I have 3 options:

- Perform the lookup in the controller method and use the separate services to persist (does not benefit from the transactional DAO methods)
- Pass the ID and the `Product` instance in a method call to the `ProductService` which would perform the user lookup using the user DAO and persist both.
- Same as previous but in the `UserService`

I'm probably missing some correct approaches but which approach follows best practice? What is the convention?

I'm using @Transactional on my DAOs so the first approach would not get and update both entities in the same transaction from what I understand.

Comment: Assuming `ProductService` already exists, the second option sounds the most reasonable. I'd strongly advise against the first one, for the exact reason you yourself mentioned. Of course, it is paramount that the method in `ProductService` be transactional as well

Comment: My services aren't transactional but my DAOs are, should i just perform the user lookup in the product DAO with the user DAO? Or is that bad practice and i should look into making my services transactional?

Comment: You should make sure that looking up the `User` and saving the `Project` are wrapped inside a transaction, otherwise at the instant the `Project` is being saved, there is no guarantee the previously looked up `User` still exists. Now, service methods are usually meant to perform business logic involving multiple DAO calls, so it is pretty logical to make them transactional. Personally, I'd perform the lookup in the service method